# Bash + urxvt: delay after ESC in Vi mode

Tags: bash, rxvt, vi-mode

I have enabled the mode prompt indicator in my `~/.inputrc` with `set show-mode-in-prompt on`. There is a delay of about half a second in the indicator when switching to normal mode after pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> but no delay in the indicator when entering insert mode. I am aware of a similar issue experienced inside of Vim and when using Tmux or Screen with Vi mode turned on (see e.g. [ESC key causes a small delay in terminal due to its Alt+ behavior](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/esc-key-causes-a-small-delay-in-terminal-due-to-its-alt-behavior)). There are solutions for each of those delays but I haven't found a way to fix the delay in my specific case (Bash + urxvt). Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That sounds like `keyseq-timeout`, which is 500 (milliseconds).  You could decrease it, e.g., to 50 (milliseconds). Setting it to zero would be a bad idea (see for example *[Re: How does one disable completion when nothing
but tabs or spaces is on the line?](http://osdir.com/ml/bug-bash-gnu/2013-01/msg00028.html)*).

Not a duplicate, but one of the answers in *[How do I switch to vi editing mode in readline?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112406/how-do-i-switch-to-vi-editing-mode-in-readline)* uses the feature:

```
# Enable Readline not waiting for additional input when a key is pressed.
# Needed for the mappings below.
set keyseq-timeout 0
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed.