# How do I use bind (or .inputrc) to map two bash commands to one key?

Tags: bash, readline

Normally, I use vi mode in bash.  It starts off in insert mode you have to hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> was it?) to get into normal (command) mode.

I also bind <kbd>↑</kbd> (up-arrow) to `history-search-backward`.

What I'd like is to make it so that when I hit up arrow, not only does it do the history-search-backward, but also sets me to normal mode.  (Sort of like tcsh behaves.)

I found a lot of related posts and people who have done clever things in .inputrc, but nothing quite like what I'm after here.  (Like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112406/how-do-i-switch-to-vi-editing-mode-in-readline) and [this](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Use_vi_shortcuts_in_terminal) in particular.)

Is this possible in bash?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
bind -m vi-move '"\e[A": history-search-backward'
bind -m vi-insert '"\e[A": " \e\e[A"'
```

(assuming that the Up key is sending a `\e[A` escape)

I don't think that's possible other than by (indirectly) binding keys to macros.

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to work perfectly.  The only other thing I had to do was change:

`bind -m vi-insert '"\e[B":    history-search-forward'`

...to...

`bind -m vi-command '"\e[B":    history-search-forward'`

...in order to get the down arrow key to work properly.