# bash readline inputrc: bind key to a sequence of multiple commands

Tags: bash, readline

I have `shift-tab` bound to `shell-expand-line` in my `.inputrc`. However, I want `shift-tab` to also insert a space character after doing the `shell-expand-line`. How can I do this?

This is what my `.inputrc` currently looks like:

```
"^[[Z": shell-expand-line
```

The `^[[Z` is what `shift-tab` looks like. I've tried the following possibilities, but they don't work:

```
"^[[Z": "shell-expand-line "
"^[[Z": shell-expand-line " "
"^[[Z": shell-expand-line" "
```

Comment: here is [a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/528528/how-do-i-use-bind-or-inputrc-to-map-two-bash-commands-to-one-key?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bindings have to specify either a builtin command, or a text macro (a string that will be inserted), not a combination of the two.  But the macro can contain another bound key sequence that *does* specify a command, plus any characters you want to insert.  As `shell-expand-line` is already bound to C-M-e in bash, all you need is

```
"\e[Z": "\e\C-e "
```

If you wanted to use a command that didn't already have such a binding, you could create an intermediate binding, such as

```
"\C-\xff": shell-expand-line
"\e[Z": "\C-\xff "
```

Comment: `\C-E` is `\C-e` -- _in the terminal_, there's no difference between ctrl and ctrl-shift. Better use `\xff` instead.

Comment: additionally for the particular case asked in the OP, there's no need for an intermediate key because shell-expand-line is by default C-M-e

Comment: @pizdelect Thanks, I hadn't tested that properly.  I made it `\C-\xff` as just `\xff` caused other side-effects.

Comment: @xdavidliu Good point, I didn't notice the default binding.  I've added the one-line solution, but leaving the "intermediate" method as it's useful for the more general case.

Comment: for some reason `"\C-\M-e "` didn't work for me; I had to use `"\e-^E "`, where the `^E` is a literal `C-e` character inserted using emacs...

Comment: I try to avoid using literals in answers because copying them to clipboard tends to turn them into the component characters (`^`, `E`).  What does `bind -q shell-expand-line` show for you?

Comment: for me, it shows `shell-expand-line can be invoked via "\e\C-e".`