# In terminal, how to delete a word when cursor is within the word?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, zsh

I want to achieve functionality similar to `c + a + w` or `d + a + w` in vim

In terminal we have `Ctrl + w` for delete a word in the left and `Alt + Backspace` from the right But I was not able to find a command to achieve this functionality

Comment: Which shell do you use?

Comment: In Bash you can try ALT+f then CTRL+w

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a shell which uses readline(3) as bash, you have either to combine two shortcuts:<kbd>Alt-d</kbd><kbd>Alt-Backspace</kbd>

Or you define a key which is not already in use, see the output of the command command `bind -sp`. The latter is already answered in [bash readline inputrc: bind key to a sequence of multiple commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548726/).

Answer (score 1):

zsh's line editor supports all of `vim`'s `[cd][ai][wW]` (even an extra `[cd][ia]a` as a bonus) out of the box when in `vi` mode (entered with `bindkey -v` like in tcsh or `set -o vi` like in `ksh`).

See [`info zsh 'Text Objects'`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-text-objects) for details.

```
$ bindkey -M viopp
"^[" vi-cmd-mode
"^[OA" up-line
"^[OB" down-line
"^[[A" up-line
"^[[B" down-line
"aW" select-a-blank-word
"aa" select-a-shell-word
"aw" select-a-word
"iW" select-in-blank-word
"ia" select-in-shell-word
"iw" select-in-word
"j" down-line
"k" up-line
```

As the documentation says, you could also bind those in `emacs` mode. Like:

```
bindkey '^W' select-a-word
```

Though in `emacs` mode, you may prefer doing it the  emacs way and navigate word-wise with  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>/<kbd>f</kbd> and delete the words forward or backward with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>¹ and maybe decide on the definition of *word* dynamically with [`select-word-style` and co.](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Widgets).

See also [Zsh zle shift selection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5407916) on the "stackoverflow"  sister site for navigation and selection (including word-wise) à la Microsoft Windows with the arrow keys if your keyboard has those.

---

<sup>¹ Well, technically that `^W` is not `emacs`-like, more like the one in the terminal line discipline.</sup>